# AngularFire Observables / Subscribe - Not Setting Class Variable in Same Scope

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm building an Ionic app using Firebase, and therefore AngularFire2. In Angularfire2 you can authenticate, but it's an observable and have to subscribe to get the user object. The problem is that I can't seem to set `this.user = user` because it doesn't seem like `.subscribe` is in the same scope.

Here's an example, I have a `auth.ts` and an `app.component.ts`. In my service, I authenticate,

*auth.ts*

```
export class AuthService {

// user: Observable<firebase.User>;
user: object = {
    displayName: null,
    email: null,
    emailVerified: null,
    photoUrl: null,
    uid: null
};

constructor(private facebook: Facebook,
            private googlePlus: GooglePlus,
            private platform: Platform,
            private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

    // this.user = afAuth.authState;
    afAuth.authState.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {

        if (!user) {
            this.user = null;
            return;
        }
        this.user =  {
            displayName: user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
            emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
            photoUrl: user.photoURL,
            uid: user.uid
        }
    });

}
```

and in my app.component.ts:

*app.component.ts*

```
export class MytApp {

rootPage: any = TabsPage;
signinPage = SigninPage;
@ViewChild('nav') nav: NavController;

userProfile: any = null;

constructor(private platform: Platform, 
            private menuCtrl: MenuController,
            private statusBar: StatusBar, 
            private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
            private authService: AuthService) {

    // this.authService.user.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
        // var user = authService.user;
        // if (user) {
        //  this.userProfile = user;
        //  this.onLoad(TabsPage);
        // } else {
        //  this.userProfile = null;
        //  this.onLoad(SigninPage);
        // }
    // });

    platform.ready().then(() => {
        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        statusBar.styleDefault();
        splashScreen.hide();

        var user = authService.user; /* HERE */
        console.log(user);
        if (user) {
            this.userProfile = user;
            this.onLoad(TabsPage);
        } else {
            this.userProfile = null;
            this.onLoad(SigninPage);
        }
    });
}

}
```

As you can see, right after `var user = authService.user;` I run `console.log(user);` and what I get is:

*console.log(user);*

```
   displayName: null,
   email: null,
   emailVerified: null,
   photoUrl: null,
   uid: null
```

I use the user object for targeting user data in Firebase, so it's necessary. The problem is that the user object isn't updated, it's like it's out of the "scope" of the `afAuth.authState.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {}`.

Any idea how I can not subscribe, and just simply get the user object, or maybe extract the data from the subscribe so that I can easily retrieve it (because it's a service) from other components? Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do a `subscribe()` in your service. What you want to do, is to return an `Observable`, and let the components handle the `Observables` themselves, and not in the service. Reason for this is because your API call is asynchronous and your components cannot wait for the resolve of the http calls.

What you can do is you can return an Observable by mapping your `AngularFireAuth` to an object that you desire.

```js
export class AuthService {
    public user: Observable<any>; //this can be any type you wish
    constructor(private facebook: Facebook,
                private googlePlus: GooglePlus,
                private platform: Platform,
                private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

        this.user =
            afAuth.authState.map((user: firebase.User) => {
                if (!user) {
                    return null;
                }
                else return {
                    displayName: user.displayName,
                    email: user.email,
                    emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
                    photoUrl: user.photoURL,
                    uid: user.uid
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Now, you can subscribe to your `AuthService.user` in any other component:

```js
export class MytApp {

    rootPage: any = TabsPage;
    signinPage = SigninPage;
    @ViewChild('nav') nav: NavController;

    userProfile: any = null;

    constructor(private platform: Platform,
                private menuCtrl: MenuController,
                private statusBar: StatusBar,
                private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
                private authService: AuthService) {


        platform.ready().then(() => {
            // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
            // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
            statusBar.styleDefault();
            splashScreen.hide();
            //subscribe to AuthService
            authService.subscribe(user => {
                console.log(user);
                if (user) {
                    this.userProfile = user;
                    this.onLoad(TabsPage);
                } else {
                    this.userProfile = null;
                    this.onLoad(SigninPage);
                }
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! Does this mean that I'll have to put every one of my firebase functions inside of a user subscribe if I want to use the `uid`? So, things like "addNewList()" or "deleteList()" that calls `db.list(this.user.uid + '/Lists/');` for example?

Comment: @Kenny techincally yes, but if you wrap your `firebase` functions into a service, say `FireBaseListService`, then what you can do is you can inject your `AuthService` into your `FireBaseListSerivce`. Then, you can use a `switchMap`. This makes you no need to subscribe in the service, and again, you can pass your `Observables` to the component to handle.