# AngularFire subscribe firing only once in my component, but works fine in my html template

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm building an Angular login app using firebase, and I am trying to subscribe to the user Observable in my component, as follows:

```
export class UserEditComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
      console.log(user);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the observable as defined in AuthService:

```
export class AuthService {

  public user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = auth.authState;
   }
}
```

This works just fine in my html template, where the following list updates properly every time the user data is updated:

```
<ul>
  <li><strong>name:</strong> {{ (authService.user | async)?.displayName }}</li>
  <li><strong>email:</strong> {{ (authService.user | async)?.email }}</li>
  <li><strong>phone:</strong> {{ (authService.user | async)?.phone }}</li>
  </ul>
```

My problem is that my subscribe function runs only once. The user object gets logged to the console only on startup. I've tried moving the code from `ngOnInit` to the constructor, but the result is the same. Shouldn't I get a new user object logged to the console every time the user is updated?

I have looked carefully at issue [AngularFire Observables / Subscribe - Not Setting Class Variable in Same Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082722/angularfire-observables-subscribe-not-setting-class-variable-in-same-scope), but I cannot see how this applies to my code, as I am doing the subscribe in the component, not the service.

*** UPDATE ***

Now I'm wondering if this is some sort of a bug, or maybe a versioning issue. I replaced the `AuthService` code with the following:

```
export class AuthService {

  public user: Observable<any>;

  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = Observable.create(function (observer) {
      setInterval(() => observer.next(new Date().toString()), 1000 );
    });
  }
}
```

This works fine, which suggests to me that the problem is somehow with the particular observable supplied by firebase. Not sure what to do about it, though. Everything I can think of is hacky.

*** UPDATE 2 ***

What appears to be happening is that the underlying user value is getting updated even though the `next` function is not being called. I am not sure why this is. I changed my `ngOnInit` to something like this:

```
export class UserEditComponent implements OnInit {

  public userCurrent: firebase.User;

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    obj = this;
    this.authService.user.pipe(first()).subscribe(user => {
      obj.userCurrent = user;
    });
  }
}
```

The value of the `userCurrent` object stays updated. I have no idea what is going on, but it works for what I need.

Comment: Are you sure they're both using the same instance of `AuthService`?

Comment: @martin If they are not using the same instance of AuthService, then how is the template being updated? Aren't they both using the object injected in the constructor?

Comment: is it possible for you to provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @Vikas I created a stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqluup. It does not reproduce the problem, however. The observable in this case is being created in the service, not merely passed along from another package. Not sure how to interpret.